# Op-amp output calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, gain

Maybe a very basic question; I am a chemical engineer with limited electronics knowledge.

The circuit is a potentiostat with the current source \$I\$ being a (gas) sensor electrode.

The 2.5 V is the bias voltage for the sensor electrode. The current will vary based on the gas concentration, and as some gas sensors have negative sensitivity, the bias voltage is required.

I was looking for a way to calculate the output of stage 2 as a function of \$I\$. I was wondering what kind of opamp configuration the first stage has? What is the best approach to solve this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJDhYf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 2.5V is the bias voltage for sensor electrode. This circuit is meant for gas sensors. The current I will vary based on the gas concentration and as some gas sensor has negative sensitivity, the bias voltage is required.

Comment: 2V not 2.5 V you have two voltage sources and one current source.

Comment: IMO the op-amp stage on the left (OA6) is a transimpedance amplifier (precision current-to-voltage converter). 2 V is another bias source (besides V 8). The op-amp stage on the right (OA 8) resembles a Howland current pump  (precision voltage-to-current converter) if the voltage across R 22 was the output voltage. So, the whole circuit acts as a current amplifier (current-to-current converter). V 7 is another bias voltage. But I don't know what is the purpose of this arrangement...

Answer (score 2):

Divide the schematic into three stages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPRWji.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

#### Green stage, 2

We are able to isolate the second green stage because it is completely independent; the behaviour of the red stage is unaffected by R7 and R8, and the near-infinite input impedance of OA6 draws no current that could influence the divider behaviour of R7 and R8.

R7 and R8 form a potential divider, with input \$V_{OUT1}\$ and output \$V_{OUT2}\$. The relationship between them is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT2} &= V_{OUT1} \frac{R_8}{R_7+R_8} \\ \\
&= V_{OUT1} \frac{1M}{200k+1M} \\ \\
&= \frac{5}{6} V_{OUT1}
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Red stage, 1

This is a transconductance stage, converting some input current into an output voltage.

Op-amp OA5 has negative feedback, the main consequence of which is that the op-amp always adjusts its output to keep its two inputs at the same potential:

$$ V_{N1} = V_{P1} = +2.6V $$

If P1 was grounded at 0V, as would be the case in a classic inverting amplifier configuration, node N1 would be referred to as a "virtual earth", for that reason. Here, though N1 is a "virtual +2.6V".

With N1 fixed at +2.6V, current \$I_2\$ is trivial to calculate with Ohm's law:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_2 &= \frac{V_{N1}-2}{R_5} \\ \\
&= \frac{2.6 - 2}{1M} \\ \\
&= 0.6\mu A
\end{aligned}
$$

The extremely high input impedance of OA5 means that it draws no current, and by Kirchhoff's current law we can state the following relationship between \$I_{IN}\$, \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{IN} &= I_2 + I_3 \\ \\
I_3 &= I_{IN} - I_2 \\ \\
&= I_{IN} - 0.6\mu A \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

That expression makes it clear why N1 is known as a "summing junction", in the parlance of [summing amplifiers](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html).

The output of OP5 is decided, then, by the voltage across R6, offset by the the potential at node N1:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT1} &= V_{N1} - I_3 (R_6 \parallel Z_{C2})\\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The impedance of C2 is \$Z_{C2}\$, which at low frequencies approaches infinity, making the parallel combination of R6 and C2 equal to R6 on its own. We can disregard C2 for frequencies from DC (0Hz) up to wherever \$Z_{C2}\$ becomes appreciable compared to R6, at which point attenuation and phase shift begin to appear. At low frequencies:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT1} &= V_{N1} - I_3 R_6 \\ \\
&= 2.6 - 147(I_{IN} - 0.6\times 10^{-6}) \\ \\
&= (2.6 - 0.6\times 10^{-6}) - 147I_{IN}
\end{aligned}
$$

The effect of +2V at the left of R5 is tiny compared to the +2.6V at N1. I imagine that this +2V source is actually adjustable, intended to nullify any small input offset voltage that the op-amps might have. If we ignore it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT1} &= 2.6 - 147I_{IN}
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Stage 3

The presence of R15 seems to complicate matters somewhat, but actually it doesn't, and it can be ignored, as I'll why explain in a moment. I'm unsure why it's there, perhaps to protect OP6 from accidental output short circuit.

Using the same trick we used for stage 1, where we noticed that the the op-amp has negative feedback, and will therefore maintain this condition:

$$ V_{N2} = V_{P2} = V_{OUT2} $$

It's important to understand that it doesn't really matter what the potential \$V_A\$ at node A actually is. Negative feedback means that the op-amp will raise or lower \$V_A\$ to obtain \$ V_{N2} = V_{P2} \$, regardless of the value of \$V_A\$ required to achieve that. In the end, all you need to know is that \$ V_{N2} = V_{P2} \$, trust that \$V_{OUT3}\$ will also be whatever it needs to be in accordance with this condition, and disregard \$V_A\$ altogether.

This means that whatever relationship we derive between \$V_{OUT3}\$ and \$V_{N2}\$, it needn't mention \$V_A\$ at all!

Let me put that another way; R15 merely represents some additional output impedance, but the op-amp compensates for that by behaving in such a way that equalises the potentials at its two inputs, *regardless of what exists in the feedback path*. If it needs to raise \$V_A\$ to make that happen, then \$V_A\$ rises. If \$V_A\$ must be lower in order for the two inputs to be equal, then \$V_A\$ falls. That's the magic of negative feedback. It doesn't care, and neither should you, what the actual value of \$V_A\$ is, all that it cares about is that \$V_{N2} = V_{P2}\$, and does whatever it must to \$V_A\$ to make it so. And when that condition is true, \$V_{OUT3}\$ must necessarily also conform to this state.

So, let's relate \$V_{OUT3}\$ and \$V_{N2}\$, and be done with it. Because OA6 input impedance is near-infinite, drawing no current from the junction of R10 and R14, we can treat those resistors as a simple potential divider between OUT3 and the +2.6V source. Therefore:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{N2} &= 2.6 + (V_{OUT3} - 2.6) \frac{R_{10}}{R_{10}+R_{14}} \\
\vdots \\
V_{OUT3} &= V_{N2}\left(1+\frac{R_{14}}{R_{10}}\right) - 2.6\left(\frac{R_{14}}{R_{10}}\right) \\ \\
&= V_{N2}\left(1+\frac{1M}{180k}\right) - 2.6\left(\frac{1M}{180k}\right) \\ \\
&= 6.56V_{N2} - 14.4 \\ \\
&= 6.56V_{OUT2} - 14.4 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

It seems crazy, but there's no mention here of R16, because it also is completely redundant. Again I reiterate that \$V_{OUT3}\$ will always be what it needs to be for \$V_{N2}=V_{P2}\$, because the op-amp does whatever it needs to do with \$V_A\$ for that condition to be true. R15 and R16 play absolutely no role in this behaviour. You could remove them both, and nothing would change. R15 could be useful, as I said, to protect OA6 from output short circuits, but it is otherwise redundant. R16 just wastes power and adds noise, that's all.

#### Combine

Starting with the equation for stage 3, and then substituting in expressions from stages 2 and 1 respectively, we get the overall input-to-output relationship:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT3} &= 6.56V_{OUT2} - 14.4 \\ \\
&= 6.56\times \frac{5}{6}V_{OUT1} - 14.4 \\ \\
&= 6.56\times \frac{5}{6}\left(2.6 - 147I_{IN}\right) - 14.4 \\ \\
&= -804I_{IN}-0.2 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Improve

If you have access to a negative supply rail for OA5, which would permit its output to go negative too, that entire circuit could be replaced with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9Y4f.png)</sup>

However, it seems that your circuit is designed to work with only ground and some positive supply, as evidenced by the use of 2.6V offsets for each op-amp.

Also, the fact that both op-amps have a +2.6V offset applied suggests that they come from the same +2.6V source, probably some kind of pseudo-ground, a mid-point between the power supply rails for the purpose of signal biasing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, let's solve and show this mathematically. We are trying to analyze the following circuit (assuming an ideal opamp):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpJj10.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{13}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_{13}=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_{13}+\text{I}_{11}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_{10}=\text{I}_8+\text{I}_9
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{c}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_\text{d}-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_6}{\text{R}_8}\\
\\
\text{I}_9=\frac{\text{V}_4-\text{V}_6}{\text{R}_9}\\
\\
\text{I}_{10}=\frac{\text{V}_6}{\text{R}_{10}}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, when we have an ideal opamp we know that \$\text{V}_\text{k}:=\text{V}_{+_1}=\text{V}_{-_1}=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_\text{a}\$ and \$\text{V}_\text{n}:=\text{V}_{+_2}=\text{V}_{-_2}=\text{V}_3=\text{V}_4\$.

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)) the fact that the resistor \$\text{R}_3\$ is replaced by a capacitor, so:

$$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag6$$

Solving your question using Mathematica, gives:

```
In[1]:=Vk = (26/10)/s;
I1 = 1/s;
Vc = 2/s;
Vd = (26/10)/s;
R1 = 47;
R2 = 10^6;
R3 = 1/(s*c);
R4 = 147;
R5 = 200000;
R6 = 10^6;
R7 = 180000;
R8 = 100;
R9 = 10^6;
R10 = 22000;
c = 220*10^(-9);
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I13 == I1 + I2, I13 == I3 + I4, I5 == I11 + I13, I5 == I6, 
   I7 == I9, I10 == I8 + I9, I1 == (V7 - Vk)/R1, I2 == (Vc - Vk)/R2, 
   I3 == (Vk - V2)/R3, I4 == (Vk - V2)/R4, I5 == (V2 - Vn)/R5, 
   I6 == (Vn)/R6, I7 == (Vd - Vn)/R7, I8 == (V5 - V6)/R8, 
   I9 == (Vn - V6)/R9, I10 == (V6)/R10}, {I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, 
   I9, I10, I11, I13, V2, Vn, V5, V6, V7}]]

Out[1]={{I2 -> -(3/(5000000 s)), 
  I3 -> 8084995149/(5000000 (50000000 + 1617 s)), 
  I4 -> 49999970/(s (50000000 + 1617 s)), 
  I5 -> (-36099977950 + 21021 s)/(6000000 s (50000000 + 1617 s)), 
  I6 -> (-36099977950 + 21021 s)/(6000000 s (50000000 + 1617 s)), 
  I7 -> (184399889750 + 21021 s)/(5400000 s (50000000 + 1617 s)), 
  I8 -> -((110473333739750 + 1282281 s)/(
    59400000 s (50000000 + 1617 s))), 
  I9 -> (184399889750 + 21021 s)/(5400000 s (50000000 + 1617 s)), 
  I10 -> -((2168898699050 + 21021 s)/(1188000 s (50000000 + 1617 s))),
   I11 -> -((1500179599889750 + 48509865789 s)/(
    30000000 s (50000000 + 1617 s))), I13 -> 4999997/(5000000 s), 
  V2 -> -((36099977950 - 21021 s)/(250000000 s + 8085 s^2)), 
  Vn -> -((36099977950 - 21021 s)/(300000000 s + 9702 s^2)), 
  V5 -> -((2663151002587750 + 25834809 s)/(
    66000 s (50000000 + 1617 s))), 
  V6 -> -((2168898699050 + 21021 s)/(2700000000 s + 87318 s^2)), 
  V7 -> 248/(5 s)}}
```

Which means, for the voltage \$\text{V}_6\$:

```
V6 -> -((2168898699050 + 21021 s)/(2700000000 s + 87318 s^2))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Aren't we looking for the output as a function of \$I\$?

Comment: @SimonFitch my last piece of code is a function of t